# Lockito like app for mocking/faking location on iOS

Tags: ios, location, tracking

I've been using [Lockito](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=fr.dvilleneuve.lockito) an Android app for mocking location routes. It lets you import a KML and GPX route and have it fake them at different speeds. Is there anything like this on iOS?

Answer (score 0):

Fake Location App [Link](http://geni.us/fakelocation)

Fliptroniks IOS Updates [link](https://fliptroniks.leadpages.co/ios-updates/)

Comment: Cannot find the app. Is this working still ?